# How to convert data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data that looks like this:

[image]

I need to convert it like this:

[image]

Basically:

- split the data by commas
- new rows should be: item[0], item[n]    <= where n=1..M

There will always be at least 2 items in the rows of the data.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using excel 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do text to columns with comma separators
2. Determine the max number of columns, or just set an upper limit. Lets call this *datalim*.
3. Reshape horisontal data into vertical on a new sheet, using INDEX, ROW, MOD etc. We will jump to a new "item[0]", every datalim'th row, leaving blanks or zeros if a row has less than datalim cells. Something like:

.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A1000, INT((ROW()-1)/datalim)+1)
```

And

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B1:ZZ1000, INT((ROW()-1)/datalim)+1, MOD(ROW()-1,datalim)+1)
```

4. Filter all the unnecessary blanks or zeros using an autofilter.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue with a more complex (more steps, and also some of them done text editor). Your solution seems ok. Thanks!